# NopCommerce creating so many guests

Tags: nopcommerce

Ok, so I see NopCommerce Creates a guest for like each page view or something.  Im not sure what the reason is.   But how do I automate deleting them?

Answer (score 3):

Customer records are created for each new (unique) visitor. But they are periodically deleted by the system (schedule tasks). So no worries here.